# Can transmit and receive with LoRa both on single uController?

Tags: stm32, lora

I want to send and receive data with two Lora module but I have only one STM32l4 nucleo board. Is it possible to connect both transmitter and receiver Lora module to this board and have a communication between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to have both a transmitter and receiver connected to a single MCU. It mostly depends on the availability of pins.

I don't know why you would want to do that as the transceivers are both transmit and receive capable. Such as the [Semtech sx1276](http://semtech.com/products/wireless-rf/lora-transceivers/).